# Why "git status" is not showing my restored changes after git reset

Tags: git, visual-studio

I was trying git in my project and accidentally typed

```
git reset --hard
```

My changes are gone and my head is now reset to last commit. Luckily Visual Studio had an option to Ignore those changes. I pressed "No to All" when asked to change files.
Now I can see changes in Visual Studio but not in "git status". Where have my changes gone and how do I get them back?

### Edit

P.S: I saved my file in Visual Studio and built the code too. Even then my code isn't shown in git diff. Sorry, I don't understand the reason for down-voting this question, but this might be a KIL (Known Issue and Limitation) for git.

I know I can copy my changes and reset the HEAD to latest commit and re-write my code. But git should be tracking changes when I pressed "No-To'All" option in Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you save your files in VS after pressing "No to All"?

Comment: you want to recover all your commit history or just want to commit the current codes to server?

Comment: If you save the changes in VS, you will see the diff in git too.

Comment: "How do I get the changes I see in the editor window onto the disk where git and other tools such as my compilers can see them?"

Comment: @vojta : Yeah. I saved the file in visual studio. And later went ahead and built it too. But the changes do not appear in git diff.

Comment: @Raptor : I want to commit my current code to server. but it is not shown in git status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kai mentioned in comment, he only wants to commit current codes to server.

Here are the steps:

1. Copy the local copy (probably with changes made) to a new folder **out of original git folder** (e.g. folder name is "source_new")
2. Remove the original git folder
3. Create a new folder to checkout from Git server
4. Remove the Git information from "source_new" folder (remove the hidden `.git` folder)
5. **Copy** the contents of "source_new" to the folder created in Step 3, overwriting files.
6. Perform commit in folder created in Step 3

If everything goes well, it is safe to delete "source_new" folder.